# Redirect a route group to a single page in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.5

what is the shortest and easy way to redirect a set of routes belonging to same route group to redirect to a common page? Like i list all the routes inside a route group and then inside the route group declaration redirect code is written.

Comment: Attach a middleware to the group which would take care of redirection

Comment: redirect a set of routes, or set or URLs?

Comment: redirect set of urls

Comment: why would you define routes to then not have them ever be used?

Comment: for example for a new project all defined routes should go to comming soon page and others should be treated as 404

Answer (score 2):

Put this inside the `route group` and it should work,

```
Route::any('{any?}', function ($any = null) {
        return Redirect::to('your_route', 301); 
})->where('any', '.*');
```